# Highcharts, How to prevent point's marker changes its color on mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a chart where each marker had different color , but when mouse is hover the marker, the point's marker changes its color to line color.

I want to disable this color change but preserve the point's glow color( [halo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.halo) )

If I use

```
hover: { enabled: false }
```

I'll lose point's glow color

http://jsfiddle.net/chofer/3v4k5y3u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addition to your code fixed it in your JSFiddle example ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v4k5y3u/5/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    fillColor: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to say I found this very unintuitive. `states.hover.marker` does not work while `marker.states.hover` does work.

Also, according to [`states.hover.marker.fillColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.marker.fillColor) the value should have been `null` not `false`, but I'm only getting the desired effect using `false` which isn't mentioned at all.